# How to see real-time update in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have a rails + react app (separate projects) and I've made an ActionCable websocket for sending simple messages from backend to the frontend. The websocket works, i can see everything on the frontend but I can't see the updates in real-time, only after refresh. I don't know how to implement the real time update.

Here is my code:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import actionCable from 'actioncable'


import { DUMMY_QUERY } from 'Queries'

// app/javascript/packs/messages.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import MessagesChannel from './channels/messages_channel'

function useForceUpdate(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // integer state
    return () => setValue(value => value + 1); // update the state to force render
}

function Dummy() {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        MessagesChannel.received = (data) => {
            setMessages(data.messages)
            console.log(data)
            }

    }, [])

   /*const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // Add the X-CSRF-TOKEN token so rails accepts the request
        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/messages', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
        })
        setMessage('')
    }*/

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {messages.map((message) => (
                    <li key={message.id}>{message.content}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dummy
```

Comment: Tried multiple methods like useForceUpdate from above, doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active cable also hat a frontend component. I have never used it together with react, but with pure js it looks something like that:

Import the lib (consumer.js):

```
import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable"

export default createConsumer()
```

Load all channels defined in your repo (index.js):

```
const channels = require.context('.', true, /_channel\.js$/)
channels.keys().forEach(channels)
```

Define a js file for each channel (message_channel.js):

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("MessagesChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

Edit: Just found out there is also a [npm package for the frontend components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable).

Comment: Can I make the last console.log(data) from received(data) print in real-time? Let's say I want to broadcast numbers from 1 to 10 with 5 seconds delay. I want to see them each appear on the page after every 5 seconds. This doesn't happen here, it only show all of them after I refresh the page..